# Why is iTunes "syncing Artwork" when no artwork has been added in weeks?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, album-art

I have sync'd iTunes to iPad several times since the last time I added any artwork.  But often, if I add a bunch of .mp3 without artwork and sync, iTunes says "Syncing artwork (step 6 of 6; waiting for items to copy."

And it will say that for **an hour or more**.

What is happening here?  It's the latest version, but previous versions have done this as well.

Comment: Is iTunes up to date?

Comment: Interestingly, I just DID add some artwork, and the subsequent sync completed rather quickly!